# unexpected token in succes row

Tags: php, jquery

```
// make AJAX call to get contents and display in DIV1 and DIV2
function ajaxRequest(div_id1, div_id2, request_url, request_params) {
    $("#" + div_id1).html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" title="Loading"/>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: request_url,
        data: request_params,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#" + div_id1).html('<br>' + response.substring(0, 1); 
            $("#" + div_id2).html(response.substring(1, 2);
        },
        error: function (req, errorMsg) {}
    })
}
```

Comment: what is the question

Comment: Your `html` methods are missing closing brackets.

Comment: html(response.substring(1, 2) <-- missing closing bracket 2 times

Comment: just check the closing brackets in ajax success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add 1 more closing parenthesis

```
 $("#" + div_id1).html('<br>' + response.substring(0, 1));
 $("#" + div_id2).html(response.substring(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some typos:

```
$("#" + div_id1).html('<br>' + response.substring(0, 1)); 
$("#" + div_id2).html(response.substring(1, 2));
```

add `)` closing of the `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Missing close brackets after `html()`

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#" + div_id1).html('<br>' + response.substring(0, 1)); 
    //                                                     ^^
    $("#" + div_id2).html(response.substring(1, 2));
    //                                            ^^
},
```